# Library to convert .docx to pdf, in WinRT app

Tags: library, pdf, c#

In a WinRT app, i can create a word file with some information filled by the user, but i also want to create a copy but as PDF(save another file with my app, not convert docx. to pdf with external software)

Any straight forward way of doing this?

Comment: You say you can "create a word file". Can you clarify what you mean and how you're doing this? As far as I know this isn't possible in WinRT so I'm curious as to what you mean. Do you mean RTF?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out a WinRT Commercial SDK that has the ability to save out PDF files such as the [LEADTOOLS WinRT SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/winrt). This SDK gives you the ability to easily save a file out as a PDF as well as many other formats such as :

JPEG, JPEG 2000, PNG, TIFF, PDF, & GIF

Here is some simple sample code on how to save out a file using the [RasterCodecs SaveAsync class](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/co/leadtools.codecs~leadtools.codecs.rastercodecs~saveasync(rasterimage,ileadstream,rasterimageformat,int32).html):

```
await codecs.SaveAsync(_originalImage, leadStream, RasterImageFormat.RasPdf, 24);
```

You can download a free 60-day evaluation of the SDK which includes fully sourced sample programs that show how to achieve various functionality using the SDK.

Just as a disclaimer, I am an employee of this library.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm using elsewhere is Pandoc (https://pandoc.org/) on a Windows box. You can schedule a PowerShell script to check a folder or something else to pick up the conversions.

```
pandoc -s -t latex README -o readme.tex
pdflatex readme.tex
```